# Whats the concept behind a CoroutineScope?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

After reading the introduction and the javadoc of [CoroutineScope](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/index.html) I'm still a little confused what the idea behind a `CoroutineScope` is.

The first sentence of the doc "Defines a scope for new coroutines." is not clear to me: Why do my coroutines need a scope?

Also, why are standalone coroutine builders deprecated? Why is it better to do this:

```
fun CoroutineScope.produceSquares(): ReceiveChannel<Int> = produce {
    for (x in 1..5) send(x * x)
}
```

instead of

```
fun produceSquares(): ReceiveChannel<Int> = produce { //no longer an extension function
    for (x in 1..5) send(x * x)
}
```

Comment: I found the description in this github issue useful to read: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/410. As explained there, "... coroutine builders like `launch { ... }` and `async { ... }` start a global coroutine by default... This seems to be a wrong default. Global coroutines are error-prone."  Now you can still do the same as the old behaviour if you want, by using `GlobalScope`, but it means you're explicitly doing this instead of accidentally doing it. And it's recommended that in most cases you shouldn't use `GlobalScope`

Comment: To cancel the job's children

Answer (score 9):

You can still use global "standalone" coroutines by spawning them in `GlobalScope`:

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    println("I'm running unstructured")
}
```

However, it's not recommended to do this since creating coroutines on a global scope is basically the same we did with good old threads. You create them but somehow need to keep track of a reference to later join/cancel them.

Using structured concurrency, that is nesting coroutines in their scopes, you will have a more maintainable system overall. For example, if you spawn a coroutine inside another one, you inherit the outer scope. This has multiple advantages. If you cancel the outer coroutine, the cancellation will be delegated to its inner coroutines. Also, you can be sure that the outer coroutine will not complete before all its children coroutines have done their work.

There's also a very good example shown in the [documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/) for `CoroutineScope`.

> CoroutineScope should be implemented on entities with well-defined lifecycle that are responsible for launching children coroutines. Example of such entity on Android is Activity.

After all, the first version of your shown `produceSquares` methods is better as it is only executable if invoked in a `CoroutineScope`. That means you can run it inside any other coroutine:

```
launch {
    produceSquares()
}
```

The coroutine created inside `produceSquares` inherits the scope of `launch`. You can be sure that `launch` does not complete before `produceSquares`. Also, if you cancelled `launch`, this would also effect `produceSquares`.

Furthermore, you can still create a globally running coroutine like this:

```
GlobalScope.produceSquares()
```

But, as mentioned, that's not the best option in most cases.

I'd also like to promote an article I wrote. There are some examples demonstrating what scopes mean: https://kotlinexpertise.com/kotlin-coroutines-concurrency/

Comment: I'm still unsure what the actual Job of a Scope is in relation to a coroutine. Its lifetime and job handling? Association with the actual threads (I mean in the end, code has to be executed by a thread, so someone, somehow needs to decide on which thread a coroutine needs to be executed)

Comment: It’s about a coroutine‘s lifecycle in the end. The `CoroutineDispatcher` (just one part of the `CoroutineScope`) defines what threads to run on. You can for example say `launch(Dispatchers.Default)` to specify a dispatcher. Otherwise, you inherit from the outer scope

Comment: @morpheus05 Don't forget that the same coroutine can pass from thread to thread, there is no single decision on which thread it will run. While it's suspended, it's not assigned to any thread, and a new decision is made each time it resumes. You can also switch threads without suspending, using `withContext`. The best mental model to use is that a coroutine's "substrate" on which it runs is a thread, just like a CPU core is the substrate on which a thread runs.

Comment: If I look at the CoroutineScope its an interface with one field, coroutineContext: CoroutineContext. But why then this interface? Can the context change during the lifecycle of a scope? Why was this interface introduced and lets say we would only work with CoroutineContext?

Comment: I have written an example (https://github.com/BILLyTheLiTTle/KotlinExperiments/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/coroutines/Scopes.kt) on my own just to understand. I am wondering, is there any advantage/disadvantage using `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {...}` instead of `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {...}` or vice versa?

Answer (score 4):

It is related to the concept of **structured concurrency**, which defines a structure between coroutines.

> [On a more philosophical level](https://medium.com/@elizarov/structured-concurrency-722d765aa952), you rarely launch coroutines “globally”, like you do with threads. Coroutines are always related to some local scope in your application, which is an entity with a limited life-time, like a UI element. So, with structured concurrency we now require that launch is invoked in a CoroutineScope, which is an interface implemented by your life-time limited objects (like UI elements or their corresponding view models).

As an evident consequence of this concept: by `cancel`ling the context of a `scope`, all it's subcoroutines will be canceled, too.