# Kotlin: Coroutines scope vs Coroutine context

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Can anyone explain the difference between them? I think scope provides a reference(e.g. Job) to cancel them and context provides a reference to underlying thread. Is that so?

Comment: You can go through this article for more details. https://medium.com/@elizarov/coroutine-context-and-scope-c8b255d59055

Comment: @Jose Hey Jose! Could you please choose an answer which you see fit?

Answer (score 68):

Yes, in principle you are right, here more details.

**Scope**

- a coroutine must run in a scope
- it's a way to keep track of all coroutines that run in it
- all ([cooperative](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative)) coroutines can be cancelled via their scope
- scopes get uncaught exceptions
- they're a way to bind coroutines to an application specific lifecycle (e.g. [`viewModelScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#viewmodelscope) in Android) to avoid leaking

**Context**

> The coroutine context is a set of various elements. The main elements
> are the Job of the coroutine, which we've seen before, and its
> dispatcher [...]. [(Source)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html)

In case you specify a dispatcher there are four options which basically determine on which thread the coroutines will run:

- **`Dispatchers.Default`** - for CPU intense work (e.g. sorting a big list)
- **`Dispatchers.Main`** - what this will be depends on what you've added to your programs runtime dependencies (e.g. [`kotlinx-coroutines-android`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/ui/kotlinx-coroutines-android), for the UI thread in Android)
- **`Dispatchers.Unconfined`** - runs coroutines unconfined on no specific thread
- **`Dispatchers.IO`** - for heavy IO work (e.g. long-running database queries)

The following example brings both scope and context together. It creates a new scope in which the coroutines will run (if not changed) on a thread designated for IO work and cancels them via their scope.

```
val scope = CoroutineScope(context = Dispatchers.IO) 
val job = scope.launch {
    val result = suspendFunc1()
    suspendFunc2(result)
}
// ...
scope.cancel() // suspendFunc1() and suspendFunc2() will be cancelled
```

Answer (score 58):

They are indeed closely related. You might say that `CoroutineScope` formalizes the way the `CoroutineContext` is inherited.

`CoroutineScope` has no data on its own, it just holds a `CoroutineContext`. Its key role is as the implicit receiver of the block you pass to `launch`, `async` etc.

See this example:

```
runBlocking {
    val scope0 = this
    // scope0 is the top-level coroutine scope.
    scope0.launch {
        val scope1 = this
        // scope1 inherits its context from scope0. It replaces the Job field
        // with its own job, which is a child of the job in scope0.
        // It retains the Dispatcher field so the launched coroutine uses
        // the dispatcher created by runBlocking.
        scope1.launch {
            val scope2 = this
            // scope2 inherits from scope1
        }
    }
}
```

You can see how the `CoroutineScope` mediates the inheritance of coroutine contexts. If you cancel the job in `scope1`, this will propagate to `scope2` and will cancel the `launch`ed job as well.

Note the key syntactical feature: I explicitly wrote `scope0.launch`, but had I written just `launch`, it would implicitly mean exactly the same thing. This is how `CoroutineScope` helps to "automatically" propagate the scope.

Answer (score 21):

`CoroutineScope` has-a `CoroutineContext`.

For example if you have:

```
runBlocking { // defines coroutineScope

    launch(Dispatchers.Default) { //inherits coroutineScope but changes context

    }
}
```

`runBlocking` defines a `CoroutineScope` (learn about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53413431/8073652)) which `launch` inherits. The context is being overridden by explicitly specifying a dispatcher here. If you look at the definition of `launch`, you can see that it takes an optional `CoroutineContext`:

```
public fun CoroutineScope.launch(
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
    ...
)
```

Another part of the context would be the coroutine's name:

```
launch(CoroutineName("launchMe") + Dispatchers.Default) {
    println("")
}
```

Comment: If you re-read your answer, you can really see you did not explain anything about the difference