# koltin, what's difference from using CoroutineScope directly and derive the class from CoroutineScope

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

when launching a coroutine it may just create a `CoroutineScope` and call launch{} from it -- the `doSomething_2()`,

or derive the class from `CoroutineScope` and with the class to launch{}. -- the `doSomething_1()`.

Is there difference between these two, which way is preferred?

```
class AClass : CoroutineScope {

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main
    
    var theJob1: Job? = null
    var theJob2: Job? = null
    
    fun doSomething_1() {
        theJob1 = launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // ... ...
        }
    }
    
    fun doSomething_2() {
        theJob2 = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            // ... ...
        }
    }
    
    fun dispose() {
        theJob1?.cancel()
        theJob2?.cancel()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there difference between these two, which way is preferred?

Yes, there's a fundamental difference that makes one correct and the other incorrect. It is about structured concurrency: if your `AClass` is the root object of your "unit of work", whatever that may be, and is in charge (or the observer) of its lifecycle, then it should also be the root scope for the coroutines you'll launch within it. When the lifecycle ends, `AClass` should propagate that event to the coroutine subsystem by calling `cancel` on itself, cancelling the root scope. `CoroutineScope.cancel` is an extension function.

I took your code and made the following fixes:

1. `CoroutineScope.coroutineContext` must have a `Job()` inside it so I added it. I removed the dispatcher because it's not relevant to this story and the `Main` dispatcher is for a GUI, while we're running a simple test.
2. I deleted your `dispose()` function, we have `cancel()` out-of-the-box.
3. I deleted `theJob1` and `theJob2` fields because they serve no purpose once you start properly using structured concurrency.

I also added some code that will allow us to observe the behavior:

4. added a `delay` into each coroutine and a `println` to see when it's done.
5. added a `main` function to test it. The function blocks forever at the last line so that we can see what the launched coroutines will do.

Here's the code:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.lang.Thread.currentThread
import kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext

fun main() {
    val a = AClass()
    a.doSomething_1()
    a.doSomething_2()
    a.cancel()
    currentThread().join()
}

class AClass : CoroutineScope {

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = Job()

    fun doSomething_1() {
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                delay(10_000)
            } finally {
                println("theJob1 completing")
            }
        }
    }

    fun doSomething_2() {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            try {
                delay(10_000)
            } finally {
                println("theJob2 completing")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you run it, you'll see only `theJob1` getting completed while `theJob2` runs for the full 10 seconds, not obeying the `cancel` signal.

This is because the construct `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)` creates a standalone scope instead of becoming the child of your `AClass` scope, breaking the coroutine hierarchy.

You could, theoretically, still use the explicit `CoroutineScope` constructor to keep the hierarchy, but then you'd have something that's clearly not the preferred way:

```
CoroutineScope(coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO).launch {
```

This would be equivalent to just

```
launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Both coroutines will be launched with equal contexts. You can see this by printing the coroutine context in both:

```
launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    println("doSomething_1 context: ${coroutineContext}")
}
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    println("doSomething_2 context: ${coroutineContext}")
}
```

This will print something like:

```
doSomething_1 context: [StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@7b8cce78, Dispatchers.IO]
doSomething_2 context: [StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@3c938006, Dispatchers.IO]
```

I haven't seen `CoroutineScope` being implemented very often outside of internal coroutine code. In this case you should favor composition over inheritance, especially since `CoroutineContext` is composable at its core, with the `+` operator. When you `launch` a new coroutine for example, the existing context is simply combined with the new context you provide.

Further reading:

- [Kotlin: Coroutines scope vs Coroutine context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54417048/5288316)
- [Why your class probably shouldn’t implement CoroutineScope](https://proandroiddev.com/why-your-class-probably-shouldnt-implement-coroutinescope-eb34f722e510)